# meaning of "pre-summoning evidence"

Tags: meaning, phrases, nouns

I read the phrase "pre-summoning evidence" in the [Times of India](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/delhi/Kejriwals-Thulla-remark-Cop-records-pre-summoning-evidence/articleshow/49230052.cms) newspaper (5 October 2015); it was describing something legal, but I am not sure about what may be its proper meaning.

The phrase in context:

> A Delhi court today recorded **pre-summoning evidence** in a criminal defamation complaint filed against [person #1]...
>
> The [person #2], who has filed the complaint, appeared before the court of Metropolitan Magistrate [person #3] and recorded his statement in support of the allegation.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly to me, the phrase *pre-summoning evidence*, when googled, returns a lot of links to news articles and very little in the way of resources with definitions.

Regardless, a legal *summons* is easily to research, and *evidence* has a straightforward definition. Thus, we can safely assume that when one gathers *pre-summoning evidence*, one is gathering evidence (presumably, against an individual) in advance of issuing a summons for that individual to appear in court.

This appears to align with the context of the [news article](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/delhi-cm-arvind-kejriwals-thulla-remark-cop-records-pre-summoning-evidence/articleshow/49229337.cms) that you are referencing.